# How do I transfer progams from my old Laptop to my new surface pro? Both use windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10

How do I transfer programs from my old laptop to my new surface pro? Both use windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

If the program *requires* installation, e.g. MS Ofice, because there are Registry changes required, there is no safe shortcut to using the program's installer.

If it is a "portable" application, such as most from MS Sysinternals or from Nirsoft, e.g. *Autoruns*, just copy the application directory from C:\Program Files\ or C:\Program Files (x86)\ to the same location on the new PC. If this is your choice, you'll also need to create new shortcuts for your Start menu.

You must know enough about the application to decide if just moving the files is sufficient.